# Junit Theories with a custom detailed exception

Tags: java, junit

Considering the following code :

```
@DataPoints
public static String[] validDates()  {
    return new String[]{
            "1930",
            "1930-10",
            "1930-50-10"};
}

@Theory
public void dateTest(String dateStr) throws DataException {
    Assert.assertEquals(Status.PASSED, verifyDate(dateStr));
}
```

Output :

```
org.junit.experimental.theories.internal.ParameterizedAssertionError: dateTest(validDates[2])
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<PASSED> but was:<FAILED>
    ...
```

Is there a way to easily modify the exception stack to be more specific, with date value "1930-50-10" instead of validDates[2] ?

try / catch AssertionError then throw another custom exception ?

Comment: we switched to https://github.com/Pragmatists/junitparams , much better.

Comment: Have you tried `Assert.assertEquals(dateStr + " failed", Status.PASSED, verifyDate(dateStr))`?

Comment: That does the trick.. simple. tanks !